# lme4 (v1.7) fails at fitting an "animal model" (LMM) compare to rrBLUP

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I would like to fit a basic "animal model" (a kind of linear mixed model, see below) using the latest version of [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/) on CRAN (v1.7). To check the results, I am fitting it on simulated data, and comparing the results with the [rrBLUP](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rrBLUP/index.html) package. However, the results of lme4 are really strange and I don't succeed in understanding why (even after reading the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19382162/597069)). My R code is available as a GitHub Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/timflutre/43daacf2c8868f609489). Any help would be much appreciated!

Notations:

- $N$: number of animals, known
- $\mu$: global mean, unknown
- $P$: number of fixed effects, known
- $X$: $N \times P$ design matrix of fixed effects, known
- $\boldsymbol{b}$: $P$-dimensional vector of fixed effects, unknown
- $W = [ \boldsymbol{1} \; X]$: $N \times (P+1)$ matrix, known
- $a = [\mu \; \boldsymbol{b}']'$: $(P+1)$ vector, unknown
- $Q$: number of "genetics" random effects (in this document, $Q=N$), known
- $Z$: $N \times Q$ design matrix of "genetics" random effects, known
- $\sigma_u^2$: variance component of the "genetics" random effects, unknown
- $A$: $Q \times Q$ matrix of additive relationships (obtained from pedigree or from molecular markers), known
- $G = \sigma_u^2 A$: $Q \times Q$ covariance matrix of the "genetic" random effects, unknown
- $\boldsymbol{u}$: $Q$-dimensional vector (often called "breeding values"), unknown
- $\sigma^2$: variance component of the errors, unknown
- $R = \sigma^2 I_N$: $N \times N$ covariance matrix of the errors, unknown
- $\boldsymbol{e}$: $N$-dimensional vector of errors, unknown
- $\mathcal{N}_N$: multivariate Normal distribution of dimension $N$

Likelihood:

$\boldsymbol{y} = W \boldsymbol{a} + Z \boldsymbol{u} + \boldsymbol{e}$ where $\boldsymbol{u} \sim \mathcal{N}_N(\boldsymbol{0}, G)$ and $\boldsymbol{e} \sim \mathcal{N}_N(\boldsymbol{0}, R)$

We also assume zero covariance between $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{e}$:

$\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{y} \\
\boldsymbol{u} \\
\boldsymbol{e}
\end{pmatrix}
= \mathcal{N}
\begin{pmatrix}
W \boldsymbol{a}, & V & ZG & R \\
\boldsymbol{0}, & GZ' & G & \boldsymbol{0} \\
\boldsymbol{0}, & R & \boldsymbol{0} & R
\end{pmatrix}
$

where $V = Var(\boldsymbol{y}) = ZGZ' + R$

Primary goal: estimate $\sigma_u^2$ and $\sigma^2$

Comment: hi, sorry I didn't answer your question via e-mail.  I will take a crack at this if I get a chance.

Comment: the only thing I can think of after a *brief* look at the code is that the translation from the internal `theta` parameters to the estimated variance-covariance matrix via `VarCorr` is not working properly/as expected (in general, one can't rely on the standard accessor methods working normally if the internal structure of the model is very different from what's expected).  Is there a scaling factor missing?  I would take a look at `lme4:::VarCorr.merMod` and see if it's doing what you think it should be doing ...

Comment: @BenBolker no need to apologize! I perfectly understand you're busy. I'll look at `lme4:::VarCorr.merMod` in the mean time.

Comment: I am voting to close this thread since OP declared that the problem was due the bug in his/her code, it was not a statistical problem.

Comment: @Tim I completely understand and am sorry for it, but does "closing the thread" means "removing it"? Because other people may be interested in keeping this example somewhere. For instance, someone up-voted the question.

Comment: @tflutre IMHO since it was a bug in your code it does not make it a statistical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, there was a bug in my script (available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/timflutre/43daacf2c8868f609489)). On line 97, instead of `relmat <- list(animal=G)`, I should have written `relmat <- list(animal=A)`. This is now corrected in the gist (v2).
So the good news is that lme4 (v1.7) indeed works quite well to fit a basic "animal model".